# How to send textfield from server to client

Tags: java

My Server class has a textfield and I am trying to send the data from textfield to the client.  But as soon as I run my server class and client class, my client class doesn't wait for my text from the server and the client ends.
I need to send the text from server to client via textfield.

`Server` class:

```
{
    PrintWriter writer = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        launch(args);
    }
        public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        BorderPane paneForTextField = new BorderPane();
        paneForTextField.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        paneForTextField.setStyle("-fx-border-color: green");
        paneForTextField.setLeft(new Label("Enter a radius: "));

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        paneForTextField.setCenter(textField);

        BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();
        // Text area to display contents
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        mainPane.setCenter(new ScrollPane(textArea));
        mainPane.setTop(paneForTextField);

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 450, 200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Server"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage

        textField.setOnAction(e -> {
            String msg; 
            msg = textField.getText();
            writer.println(msg);
            writer.flush();
            System.out.print("Enter Message ('Bye bye' to exit): ");
        });

        System.out.println("Server stats.");
        InetAddress serverBindAddress = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_BIND_ADDRESS);
        try (ServerSocket listeningSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_LISTENING_PORT, SERVER_BACKLOG,
                serverBindAddress)) {
            listeningSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            try (Socket socketCommWithClient = listeningSocket.accept();
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);) {
                writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socketCommWithClient.getOutputStream()));
                socketCommWithClient.setReuseAddress(true);
                writer.println("Hello, client. I am the server.");
                writer.flush();
                System.out.println("Server: " + "Hello, client. I am the server.");

                System.out.print("Enter Message ('Bye bye' to exit): ");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.getStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (writer != null) {
                        writer.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

`Client` class:

```
{
    String serverAddress = SERVER_ADDRESS;
    int serverPort = SERVER_PORT;
    BufferedReader brReader = null;
    Socket socket = new Socket();

    try {
        SocketAddress serverSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(serverAddress), serverPort);
        socket.connect(serverSocketAddress);

        brReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = brReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line); 
            if (line.equals("Bye bye")) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("File I/O or network I/O error.");
    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to close the server socket.");
            }
        }
        if (brReader != null) {
            try {
                brReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("I/O error.");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Your server never reads anything after writing the initial message.  It closes the connection immediately.  What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: I would need the Client to wait for the Server.  When I input a text and hit Enter in the textfield of the server, the text will display on the client side like sending a phone text to someone.